# Serialization empty

Tags: restsharp

I try to serialize a custom object, but it ends up being empty.

The result I want to have is :

```
{
"accessRules": [
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/*"
    }
],
"redirection":"https://www.mywebsite.com/"
}'
```

Here are my classes:

```
[Serializable]
    public class AccessRule
    {
        [SerializeAs(Name = "method")]
        string Method { get; set; }

        [SerializeAs(Name = "path")]
        string Path { get; set; }

        public AccessRule(string method, string path)
        {
            this.Method = method;
            this.Path = path;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class RequestBody
    {
        [SerializeAs(Name = "accessRules")]
        AccessRule[] AccessRules
        {
            get { return arList.ToArray(); }
        }

        private List<AccessRule> arList;

        [SerializeAs(Name = "redirection")]
        string Redirection { get; set; }

        public RequestBody(string method, string path, string redirection)
        {
            this.arList = new List<AccessRule>();
            this.arList.Add(new AccessRule(method, path));
            this.Redirection = redirection;
        }
    }

var RequestBody = new RequestBody("GET", "/*", "https://www.mywebsite.com");
```

And it leads to an empty json string.

If i do :

```
var RequestBody = new { accessRules = new[] { new { method = "GET", path = "/*" } }, redirection = "https://www.mywebsite.com" };
```

It works.

I use RestSharp 104.4.0.0, also tried with Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.0.0

What am I missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like the serializer is missing in your demo code. could you please include the lines used to serialize the object?

Comment: Hi,
I tried to serialize using NewtonSoft.Json so : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestBody); or directly with Restsharp serializer : Request.AddBody(RequestBody);